# Unknown DC-DC topology

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, switching, bms, topology

I am working with a BMS that has a daughterboard attached that I assumed was a DC-DC converter but now I am not so sure. Here is the broad circuit overview that I have derived:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fws22w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have omitted the drive circuitry for M1 and M2, but this is the gist of it. The input power to the BMS comes from the B+. That node comes from the battery positive, to the daughterboard, and also directly out to the output of the pack, meaning B+ = Pack+.

There is not an output positive from this daughterboard, only the B- and Pack- outputs. I considered maybe a switchable load but there is no resistive element. There are also snubbers across the FETs and diode which implies high power switching. This does not match any DC-DC topology I've come across.

If anyone has any insight into this please let me know.

Comment: Try a schematic that isn't blurred. Don't omit details unless you are totally sure they are unnecessary.

Comment: @Andyaka Seems [SE/CircuitLab integration](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6287/circuit-image-resolution-is-poor) is to blame for the blurriness - given the OP went to the effort of using the builtin schematic editor, not really their fault. If you click "simulate this circuit" it will show in higher resolution.

Comment: This could act as a buck converter during charge mode to control current and cut off voltage.

Comment: edited for clarity of pack location